# Error while in a script for converting a folder of jpg to png for mac

Tags: png, jpeg

I have a folder with a lot of jpg files and I want to convert them all into png. The thing is that I want to keep the name of the files. Let's see if you can help me.

```
#! /bin/bash

unset i2
for i in ./drawable/*.jpg 
do
    $i2 = ${i%%.jpg}
    sips -s format png $i --out Converted/$i2.png
done
```

Comment: Allocating `$i2` will fail. Use `i2=...` instead. Your output path is wrong as well. As of now, you output files are stored as `Converted/./drawable/file.png`. Try playing around with `basename`. You don't need the `unset i2` either. As a general programing tip, you should use more readable variable name. Naming variable x, y, i1, ... i99 leads to errors due to name confusion.

Comment: Could you put the final code? With so many mistakes I don't know what I have to change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a corrected version of your code :

```bash
#! /bin/bash

#you don't need to unset variables in bash if you want to reuse them

#for your script to be more portable, I would rather use 'for IMG in ./*.jpg'
#that way, you could execute the script anywhere on your computer with any .jpg file.
#with your current syntax, the script will fail if there is no ./drawable folder
for IMG in ./drawable/*.jpg
do
    IMG_BASENAME=$(basename $IMG)  #this will convert './drawable/img.jpg' to 'img.jpg'
    sips -s format png $IMG --out Converted/${IMG_BASENAME%%.jpg}.png
    #again, if you want the script to be portable, I would suggest using a fixed output directory
    #for instance : sips -s format png $IMG --out ~/Documents/Converted/${IMG_BASENAME%%.jpg}.png
done
```

Comment: I have this error. I have copied it exactly and executed it with sh and the name of the script. Is it correct? Why is this happening?

imageconverter: line 5: IMG_BASENAME: command not found
/Users/mmolins/Desktop/drawable/wh_world_war_ii_end.jpg
Error: Unable to write image to file /Users/mmolins/Documents/Converted/.png.VQIQ7
  /Users/mmolins/Documents/Converted/.png

Comment: @mxmolins ahaha I just tried my script with dummy values, and it is just an error due to spaces around the `=` sign :) I'll edit my answer

Comment: @mxmolins you will have to create the folder `./Converted` (or `~/Documents/Converted` if you are following my recomendations) if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @mxmolins is it working for you ? I use a Linux system, so there might be some differences between the behaviour I get and the one on a Mac